# What is the purpose of `<<=` in Java?

Tags: java, string, bitwise-operators

So, I saw this code for converting ascii to binary:

```
String s = "foo";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();

StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : bytes)
{
    int val = b;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        val <<= 1;
    }
    binary.append(' ');
}
System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);
```

In this context, what does the `<<=` operator do? How exactly does this code build a binary representation of `s`?

Comment: Read up on [bitwise and shift operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Comment: And binary what? What "binary representation" is that? Note that you `.getBytes()` without specifying the encoding; if I `.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)` I will obtain a different result than if I `.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`.

Comment: What does your reference book say it does?

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is a shift operator. It shifts the bits x places to the left. `<<=` combines the shift operator with assignment. So `val <<= 1` is the same as `val = val << 1` which takes the bits of val and shifts them one place to the left.